# React Context API change context without re-rendering provider

Tags: reactjs, react-context

I'm relatively new to React and I'm struggling with one thing. I have an app which has many nested components. I set up a `Context` for them. There's a child component (context consumer) that I want to be able to change the context with. And I don't want to trigger re-renders only in components that use this context.

However, I cannot really change the context value in the consumer. The only thing I was able to come up with is this:

```
import { createContext, useContext, useState } from "react";

interface ContextType {
  message: string;
  setMessage: (value: string) => void;
}

const Context = createContext<ContextType>({} as ContextType);

const Consumer1 = () => {
  const { message, setMessage } = useContext(Context);
  return (
    <div>
      {message}
      <button onClick={() => setMessage("bar")}>Change context</button>
    </div>
  );
};

const Consumer2 = () => {
  return <div>Consumer2</div>;
};

const App = () => {
  const [message, setMessage] = useState("foo");
  const value = { message, setMessage };
  return (
    <div>
      <Context.Provider value={value}>
        <Consumer1 />
        <Consumer2 />
      </Context.Provider>
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```

CodeSandbox link: [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/purple-hill-j2ynwn?file=/src/App.tsx:0-762).

So, basically when I click the button in `Consumer1`, it triggers a context change, but the thing is - the context value is the `App` (context provider) state. That's why it works, I am basically re-rendering `App`, so it can pass the newly changed value via the provider. `Consumer1` reads the new updated value and all is good. However, `Consumer2` also gets re-rendered here, because its parent got re-rendered.

I guess my question is simple: is there a way to trigger a context change in the consumer without re-rendering the provider (which is usually a parent for many components) - so the only components re-rendered are the ones that use the context? Or isn't that possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not possible to update a state without causing re-render.

But what you can do is to separate that logic in different provider component, rather than the App itself.

```
const MessageProvider = ({children}) => {
  const [message, setMessage] = useState("foo");
  const value = { message, setMessage };

  return <Context.Provider value={value)>{children}</Context.Provider>
}
```

and then use it wherever you like

```
const App = () => (
   <MessageProvider>
      <Consumer1>
      <Consumer2>
      <SomethingThatWontRerender />
      <SomethingElse />
   </MessageProvider>
)
```

This way you will rerender only the provider and the consumers

Comment: Oh, this is good. This is the time when my lack of knowledge about React is really showing. Let's take a look at your example. I thought that "if parent's state changes, then the child also gets re-rendered" applies both to: when `App` changes and when `MessageProvider` changes - because `Consumer1`, `Consumer2` are "inside" `MessageProvider`. However, I pasted your code to CodeSandbox and when I change the context in `Consumer1`, `Consumer2` doesn't get re-rendered. Why is that? Both `Consumer1` and `Consumer2` are `MessageProvider`s children, so why don't they both get re-rendered?

Comment: Is it because `MessageProvider` receives children not directly but via props and when its state changes - it cannot modify its own props?

Comment: <Comp /> This thing converts into React.createElement(Comp) and it returns an object. Since in JS objects are compared by reference, on each render it returns new object. Rerender happens when that object has different reference. Children are converted into component instance inside the App and passed into MessageProvider, that way even if MessageProvider does rerender, children's reference stays the same and that prevents the rerender

Comment: in your example Consumer2 is not a consumer actually, it is just a component. Consumers are those that use that context. When value in context provider changes, all its consumers get rerendered

Comment: Okay, thanks. And yeah, I know, `Consumer2` is not a consumer, I just copied `Consumer1` and removed `useContext`, without changing the name.  But I used your solution in my project + I've also seen it used in articles etc., so that's good. Again thanks!